# Override jQuery Validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to user jQuery Validation plugin to validate a signup form, but I also do an ajax check to see if a username is available. If it's not available, I want to dynamically set the validation to fail on the username field and show an error message so the user can try another name.

Here's the code:

```
$.post("/app/signup/username/", {
    username: checkUsername
    },
    function(response){
        //$('#usernameResult').html(unescape(response)).fadeIn();
        if (response.length > 1) {
             $('#signup').validate().showErrors({"username":"Username not available"});
             $('#username').valid() = 0;
        } else {
             $('#signup').validate().element('#username') = false;
             $('#username').valid() = 1;
        }
});
```

It's showing the error message correctly but I'm not sure how to set the field so that jQuery validation sets it to fail so the form can't be submitted if the name is taken, `$('#username').valid() = false;`

did not work.

Any insights appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can `return false;` inside the form submission method to stop the submission. This might work. I', not sure where your code is, so more context could be helpful if this solution doesn't work.